# How to fetch a specific value from a HTML using BeautifySoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to bring the percent value from a HTML file. I used the below two method in juypter Notebook and got the result as expected in both the method. But while I am trying to replicate the same in pycharm I am not getting expected result in either of the method. I am getting None in second method and picking another word in the first method

```
spans = soup.select_one('span').text
print("spans:", spans)
>> spans 99%

spans = soup.find("span", {"class": "rc_late"}).text
print("spans", spans)
>> spans 99%
```

Here is snipper of the HTML. Is there any way we can fetch those value (99%)?

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>Latest report:
        <span class="rc_late">99%</span>
    </h1>
    <aside id="help_panel_wrapper">
        <input id="help_panel_state" type="checkbox">
        <label for="help_panel_state">
            <img id="keyboard_icon" src="keybd_closed.png" alt="Show/hide keyboard shortcuts">
        </label>
        <div id="help_panel">
            <p class="legend">Shortcuts on this page</p>
            <div class="keyhelp">
                <p>
                    <kbd>n</kbd>
                    <kbd>s</kbd>
                    <kbd>m</kbd>
                    <kbd>x</kbd>
                    <kbd>c</kbd>
                    &nbsp; change column sorting
                </p>
                <p>
                    <kbd>[</kbd>
                    <kbd>]</kbd>
                    &nbsp; prev/next file
                </p>
                <p>
                    <kbd>?</kbd> &nbsp; show/hide this help
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <form id="filter_container">
        <input id="filter" type="text" value="" placeholder="filter...">
    </form>
    <p class="text">
        created at 2023-01-22 12:01 +0000
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it, given your example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<div class="content">
    <h1>Latest report:
        <span class="rc_late">99%</span>
    </h1>
    <aside id="help_panel_wrapper">
        <input id="help_panel_state" type="checkbox">
        <label for="help_panel_state">
            <img id="keyboard_icon" src="keybd_closed.png" alt="Show/hide keyboard shortcuts">
        </label>
        <div id="help_panel">
            <p class="legend">Shortcuts on this page</p>
            <div class="keyhelp">
                <p>
                    <kbd>n</kbd>
                    <kbd>s</kbd>
                    <kbd>m</kbd>
                    <kbd>x</kbd>
                    <kbd>c</kbd>
                    &nbsp; change column sorting
                </p>
                <p>
                    <kbd>[</kbd>
                    <kbd>]</kbd>
                    &nbsp; prev/next file
                </p>
                <p>
                    <kbd>?</kbd> &nbsp; show/hide this help
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <form id="filter_container">
        <input id="filter" type="text" value="" placeholder="filter...">
    </form>
    <p class="text">
        created at 2023-01-22 12:01 +0000
    </p>
</div>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
data_we_want = soup.select_one('span[class="rc_late"]').text
print(data_we_want)
```

Result in terminal:

```
99%
```

You can find BeautifulSoup documentation [here](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).